# What simple test-case and corresponding solution, would demonstrate what it is possible to achieve using causation/precedence-analysis techniques

Tags: hypothesis-testing, causality

What would be minimal test-case(s) and corresponding solution, demonstrating curent know-how in causation/precedence analysis solving, or more simply
what is it possible to achieve using causation/precedence analysis techniques since the field seems to have evolved fast during the last decade:

Statistics calculations have a cost and are often used to convince rather than used as a way to know the truth. 
May-be is it because actual hability of statistics to analyse facts is still limited to correlation rather than causation.
[SEM path analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling), went popular surprizingly in social, behavioural science and psychology, trough the use of [LISREL](http://www.ssicentral.com/lisrel/), but seems still not be used to build survey or analyse survey results.
later, Judea Pearl in 2011  and Leslie Lamport 2013 won the ACM Turing award (IT Nobel) on subjects related to causation.

Artificial intelligence needs to optimize some form of truth, using causation. But its optimisation process should be improved by including intuitive-like strategies where [comfirmatory hypothese analysis](http://psychology.wikia.com/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling) would help a lot, ..."I believe".
I imagine that Causation analysis is part of recent IA achievments in a way or another. But practically how ? What test-case were solved ?

Comment: How is "state of the art" defined here? I don't mean to be facetious, I genuinely don't know exactly what exactly you'd be trying to demonstrate.

Comment: @user1767316 I think the question may be very interesting, but I am afraid you will not receive a satisfying answer here. By migrating it to [stats.se] the question will not disappear from this site, but an entire new audience (that may have more experience with LISREL and multivariate analyses) will be able to look at the question and formulate an answer

Comment: to @ancientcampus: I am not trying to demonstrate anything but rather to get the most efficient know-how regarding concrete test-cases.  I use the "state of the art" expression to encourage others to provide us with what they believe is both the most important and conretly efficient in the field.